# filter array with lodash

Tags: arrays, object, lodash

I have an array and i need to filter it. What happen is that if i use

```
var results = _.filter(arr, function (ob) {
                        return ob.VAL.indexOf(search) !== -1;
                    });
```

all the objects are returned cause they contain '0@1900-01-01' .I just want the first one to be returned

```
search='0@1900'
arr=[
{
    "DSR_MOTIVO": "Falta de nada",
    "VAL": "0@1900-01-01@111@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSR_MOTIVO": "Falta de Plano",
    "VAL": "100@1900-01-01@111@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSR_MOTIVO": "Fabrica Encerrada",
    "VAL": "100@1900-01-01@150@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSR_MOTIVO": "Refeicoes",
    "VAL": "200@1900-01-01@212@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSR_MOTIVO": "Lanche/WC",
    "VAL": "200@1900-01-01@213@1900-01-01"
  }  
]
```

Maybe a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `_.startsWith`

```
var results = _.filter(arr, function (ob) {
                                    if(_.startsWith(ob.VAL, search)`enter code here`){
                                        return ob.VAL;
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first match, the _.find function should do the job:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#find